# How to upload pdf file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

When I upload pdf file using my asp.net web app, I get that is Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): Unknown error.

Comment: Does the uploading part work for other filetypes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not due to the file type, but the file size.  By default, uploads are limited to 4 MB.  Update `web.config` to increase your maximum request length.  For example, setting `maxRequestLength` to `102400` will allow you to accept up to 100 MB; just be sure you want to allow that much data to be posted to your server.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="size in kb" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think before file upload you should clear your browsing data in your browser.

Just use simple Save as method of file upload control to upload pdf file.

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Path where to save pdf file)
```

Comment: No, Ohter file such as image, text is accept. this course it only pdf file. Please help me.